# BeginForm not showing initial Dropdown List Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, kendo-ui

I am using BeginForm and the initial value of one of the Dropdown's is not being set properly.  The value is held in a SelectLitemItem and is correctly shown in the preceding Table (in the Index view).  The available values provided for list are also correct.  It always defaults to "Create" which has a value of "1" even when it should be "Update" which has a value of "2".

The Model.RuleType.Value is shown correctly if I just display it on the form.

I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.  I can see no duplicate ID/ Name and have tried including a Hidden field.

There is another dropdown that happens to use a common value for both Value and Text and that works.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```cs
@model AMS.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.RuleActionModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID) 
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RuleType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Partial("Partials/_RuleTypeDropdown") @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RuleType)
            </div>
        </div>
```

**RuleTypeDropdown**

```cs
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("RuleType")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("RuleTypeList", "List", new { Area = "Admin" });
        });
    })
)
```

**Model**

```cs
public class RuleActionModel
{
    public RuleActionModel() { }
    public RuleActionModel(RuleAction ruleAction) 
    {
        ...
        RuleType = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = ruleAction.RuleType.ToString(),
            Text = ((RuleType)(ruleAction.RuleType)).EnumToString()
        };
    }
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public SelectListItem RuleType { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    RuleAction ruleAction = UnitOfWork.RuleActionRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    if (ruleAction == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    var model = new RuleActionModel(ruleAction);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` element to a complex object (in your case `SelectListItem`) You `RuleType` property needs to be typeof `RuleAction` (or typeof `string`)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `RuleType` (not `RuleAction`) assuming `RuleType` is an enum.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - I changed it to a string and that did it.

Comment: If its is an enum, the you should make the property the enum, not string. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rnkEx1) for an example